# How to query a range from a date value in Google Sheets

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-query-language

I'm trying to query the full range of Assignment Names that correspond to a particular "Proffer Date", in this case 4/17/2019 in this sheet:

[image]

and import them into this sheet:

[image]

so that ideally I get the Assignment names in E2:E5 (Big Switch - Chris, Big Switch - Patrick, Verafin, etc.)

To do this I've been trying an API query:

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JUF_ptZQ- 
Xi01jCUpCtQPJECydJlwF8ixHAcrWbFyZo/edit#gid=1823646744","Assignment 
Structure (by client)!H:N"),"select Col1 where Col3 = '4/17/2019'" ,1)
```

in cell F2, but it's only returning the first row, i.e. "Assignment Name".

How can I adjust this query to return the full range of Assignment names that have proffer dates of 4/17/2019?

Thanks in advance! Apologies for the imgur links but this is my first question and I don't have any reputation ;)

Comment: I'm astonished that it gave you any response seeing that the proffer date is in the equivalent of column 7 (rather than Col3 as in your formula)..

Comment: That confused me too, it doesn't seem to matter which column I select for that segment, it returns the first value of column 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `query` and a date is used for comparison "*Use the keyword date followed by a string literal in the format yyyy-MM-dd.*" [Per Query Language documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#literals).

Your query should look like this:

```
`=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JUF_ptZQ-Xi01jCUpCtQPJECydJlwF8ixHAcrWbFyZo/edit#gid=1823646744","Assignment Structure (by client)!H:N"),"Select Col1 where Col7 = date '2019-4-17'" ,1)`
```

NB: Ensure that the entries in Column N (Proffer Date) are formatted as dates (check with `isdate()`) and are formatted as dates.